# Have there been new discoveries concerning the perception of taste for the last 10 years?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, neuroscience, human-anatomy

What are the last discoveries concerning the perception of taste for the last 10 years?
We discovered the 5th flavour: umami.
Also the 6th and 7th: oleogustus and starchy. 
Anything else?
Maybe in genetics, as we all have genetic predisposition?
Or concerning the creation of the systems in charge of the perception of taste during the embryo-genesis?

Comment: We welcome new users to SE Biology, but ask that they bear in mind that this is "a question and answer site", not a discussion site. "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." This question does not fall into that category, but is a broad question about a field, inviting subjective answers. Furthermore, you provide no evidence of having searched the literature for reviews on this topic. Sorry, but I have voted to close.

Comment: The field of chemosensation is an active field of research. The answer to all your questions is yes. So, so much has been discovered in the last decade, both regarding detection by sensory neurons, genetics, behavior, the (embryological) development of these systems, and the coding of tastes and odors in the brain. What's more, there are many model organisms used to study this (insects [flies, moths, locusts, mosquitoes, etc.], worms, mice, zebrafish as well as in vitro methods (e.g. electrophysiology) currently in use.  Sadly you'll have to narrow down your questions to get concrete answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on exactly what you're interested in, but the short answer is *yes*, there have been discoveries related to the perception within the last 10 years.

The example that comes to mind is the role of the cannabinoid 1 receptor in the sense of taste of lipids.  The full text of a good article is available online [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6643/10/10/1347/htm).

---

#### Source:

Brissard L et al. 2018. Orosensory Detection of Dietary Fatty Acids Is Altered in CB1R−/− Mice. Nutrients 10(10): 1347.